# json property with value and object at the same time

Tags: json

Is there any way to set a property with its own value and an object at the same time?

Here and example what I would like to achieve:

```
"menu":{
"about": "About",
"home": "Home",
"user": "User",
"site": "Site", {
  "list":{
    "title": "Main Office"
  }
}
```

},

Following this example, I would like to be able to call **menu.site** and **menu.site.list.title**

Regards fellows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a valid json, however you can set `site` as a list like this

```
{
    "menu": {
        "about": "About",
        "home": "Home",
        "user": "User",
        "site": [
            "Site",
            {
                "list": {
                    "title": "Main Office"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and then access menu.site[0], menu.site[1].list.title